# Using custom dimensions in the Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In Google Analytics, I am able to create a report based off a custom dimension, let's call it `Battery Level`. In the [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on?hl=en) I can create a report with the [standard dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on/#dimensions). However I can't specify my custom dimension in my report. Using the report wizard, or writing the parameters by yourself doesn't allow for selecting any custom dimensions.

This seems at odds with the implementation of the rest of the add-on, which can connect back to your GA account for other customised aspects, such as selecting your custom `View (Profile) ID / ids`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

I found my answer [here](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/08/10/custom-dimensions-google-analytics/)

"...first load the GA Add-On from the Chrome extension gallery, then choose “Create new report” and select your GA view. To access custom dimensions (or metrics), you will need to select “Custom Dimension XX”, and change the XX later. When you click “Create Report” you’ll see the “Report configuration” tab."

and...

"Edit your report configuration by changing the XX in “ga:dimensionXX” to the actual dimension index number, as in “ga:dimension5”. To find your custom dimension index numbers, go to the GA admin panel and look under Property Settings > Custom Definitions > Custom Dimensions."